How to change the /home size of an OCI virtual machine?
What is the best way to specify the size of the /home partition while creating an OCI VM? Is this something that could be controlled through the available OCI Terraform modules? I did look up the Terraform registry (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/oracle/oci/latest/docs) for Oracle Cloud but couldn't find anything.
